# Python-requests POST JSON-formatted text string using data originating from Pandas DataFrame, looping through DataFrame records

Tags: json, pandas, for-loop, post, python-requests

I have a basic Pandas DataFrame with 3 datapoints (columns) per record. These datapoints need to be JSON-formatted and sent as an HTTP POST request using the requests library, and when the code is run it needs to loop through each record in the DataFrame (10 df records = 10 POST requests). I am able to successfully send a single request, but when using the loop below I get an error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)."

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

d = {'UID': [1111,2222,3333], 'ID':[29,29,30], 'updatedDate':['2020-04-13','2020-04-13','2020-04-13']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    payload = f'{{"uniqueIds": ["{row.UID}"], "changes": {{"style": {{"id": {row.ID}}}}}, "updatedDate": "{row.updatedDate}"}}'
    requests.post(url,headers=(custom headers),data=payload)
```

The properly formatted JSON I need to send in the POST request looks like this (the f-string above formats this properly):

{"uniqueIds": ["1111"], "update": {"style": {"id": 29}}, "updatedDate": "2020-04-13"}

{"uniqueIds": ["2222"], "update": {"style": {"id": 29}}, "updatedDate": "2020-04-13"}

{"uniqueIds": ["3333"], "update": {"style": {"id": 30}}, "updatedDate": "2020-04-13"}

If I create a string variable `payload = '{"uniqueIds": ["1111"], "update": {"style": {"id": 29}}, "updatedDate": "2020-04-13"}'` and send the exact same requests request (standalone, outside of the for loop), the request is successful. Including it in the for loop as written above causes the error specified.

I have been searching for similar errors but haven't quite been able to piece it together. My specific question is this: how can I loop through my DataFrame to send these requests in the JSON format specified? I'm open to other approaches - my basic requirements are to start from DataFrame, send HTTP POST with the specifically-formatted JSON in body, and do it as many times as there are records in the DataFrame. Apologies, but I can't provide a fully reproducible example (url / headers) due to privacy protection. I'm hoping the info provided is enough, or that someone has run into a similar issue in the past. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across this, solution was very simple, as I thought it might be. I needed a `continue` statement at the end of my for loop.

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    payload = f'{{"uniqueIds": ["{row.UID}"], "changes": {{"style": {{"id": {row.ID}}}}}, "updatedDate": "{row.updatedDate}"}}'
    requests.post(url,headers=(custom headers),data=payload)
    continue
```